# passing id to popout div that loads external page

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following. my problem is when i click on a item, i want to grab the id from the item and pass it over to a popup div. for some reason its not working. here is what i have.

html

```
<p class="clickme" id="1">popout</p>
```

jquery

```
$('.clickme').click(function(){ 
    var item = $(this).attr('id'); //alert(item); works fine
             $.post('pop.php', {itemclick:item, box:'890'} ,function(data) {
            $('#loadIn').html(data).show(); 
            });         
    });
```

external page

```
echo "this is the pop page data"; //shows up
echo $_POST['itemclick']; //nothing shows up
```

external page only displays this is the pop page data. I can alert the trigger so i know a variable is set, but it doesn't shows up on pop.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Even though I was able to run jquery and trigger the click, I also needed to wrap `$(document).ready()` around the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.clickme').click(function(){ 
    var item = $(this).attr('id');
    $.post('pop.php', {itemclick:item, box:'890'} ,function(data) {
      $('#loadIn').html(data).show(); 
    });         
  });
});
```